# Datatables column().data() paginated

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Is there a way to return the given data in 1 unpaginated array? i can't think of a proper way.

Javascript:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var newData = table.columns(5).data();

console.log(newData);
```

Console output:

[image]

return something like this -> ***[0 ... 439]***.

**EDIT**

Also, how can i convert the strings to int after get the inpaginated data?

[image]

Comment: You are totally misreading the console. The above `► [.....]` is just a convenient way for the developer tools to show output. The alternative is ultra long outputs that would take forever to render.  You **do** get `data()` as a long not paginated array.  I guess `console.dir()` would return something you can recognise better, or perhaps a `stringify()` you can copy paste to a JSON formatter ....

Comment: Thanks for your comment. yeah i didn't use `console.dir()` to see the data data. but my problem is still on how to combine the paginated value as 1.

Comment: The array is NOT "paginated", neither is the output from `table.columns(5).data()` ...How should it be that? I dont know any feature in javascript that allows paginated arrays ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a getter essentially

You can display the data unpaginated by setting this property:

```
"bPaginate": false,
```

as part of the config object you pass during initialization - looks something like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]], //sort first col descending
    "bFilter": false,//disable filtering
    "bPaginate": false, // no pagination
} );
```

or you can fetch just the current page flat:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var newData = table.columns(5, {page:'current'}).data();
```

or you can grab them all and just concatenate them yourself:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var newData = table.columns(5).data();
var flatNewData= [].concat.apply([], newData );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need the data paginated in the view so i can't  set `'bPaginate': false`. 
i try to concat base on your var `flatNewData` but it only concat the curret page, coz i need all data from the other pages as 1 whole array of data.

Comment: @jefsama there was a typo in my answer - sorry. I edited my last code-snippit to grab all pages and flatten them into one array. 
The page:'current' bit is another approach if you just wanted to grab one page as a flat array